# tarArchive ExtractContents() make Exception creating directory '*' because a file or directory with the same name already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filestream

I wrote a program with asp.net core I would extract tar archive files and I have used this method.

```
tarArchive.ExtractContents(destPathFolder)
```

but I got error  Exception creating directory '*' because a file or directory with the same name already exists. I don't know how to resolve this issue I have done a lot of searches but I couldn't solve my issue.

for example, the blow address is a place I would extract my files.

> C:\data\634192CC-FDCB-4711-BD41-B0F7A7E77148\BAF59489-C7F9-4747-A0A1-B3C7A94FFFD4-2019-12-08
>   14-47-19\task-2019-12-08 21-13-20

this method extract tar archives files that have text files. It means if we have image files we will get that error.

```
static void ExtractTar(Stream inStream, String destFolder)
{
    string sourcePath = Path.Combine(destFolder , "/data" );
    Stream tarStream = new TarInputStream(inStream);
    TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(tarStream);
    tarArchive.ExtractContents(sourcePath );
    tarArchive.Close();
    tarStream.Close();
    inStream.Close();
}
```

---

I have changed to this code but I have got Access path to "" is denied.

```
     static void ExtractTar(string addressFile, string destFolder)
   {
      Stream inStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(addressFile);
      TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(inStream);
      tarArchive.ExtractContents(destFolder);
      tarArchive.Close();    
      inStream.Close();

   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by " It means if we have image files we will get that error." ?

Comment: @NanYu, It means sometimes we have a text file inside tar archive file I can extract text files from tar archive file but sometimes we have images inside it. but I can't extract images files (for example multiple images).

Comment: Sometimes ? Can you confirm which condition make  multiple images not working ? It works in my testing with  multiple images

Comment: @NanYu, I have changed my code and I have added in my question but now I got Access path to "" is denied error. of course, destFolder and addressFile are the same paths.

Comment: Do you host on IIS or in vs ?

Comment: @NanYu, in Visual Studio 2019 but in general my program is a self-contained and it works without IIS.

Comment: That is permission issue . Did you try to run vs as administrator for testing .

Comment: @NanYu, I did it but it doesn't work.